# android-billing : BillingClient.acknowledgePurchase() twice in short time get DEVELOPER_ERROR

Tags: android-billing

I refer to [google sample BillingRepository.kt](https://github.com/android/play-billing-samples/blob/master/TrivialDriveKotlin/app/src/main/java/com/kotlin/trivialdrive/billingrepo/BillingRepository.kt) to implement my BillingRepository;
As Google advises that developer should call BillingClient.queryPurchases() at onResume() callback;

So when I purchase an item successfully, I got the following code path:

- onPurchasesUpdated() --> first acknowledgePurchase()
- BillingRepository.queryPurchasesAsync() ---> second acknowledgePurchase()

  - The play store purchase flow Activity finished and MyActivity get onResume() callback to invoke BillingRepository.queryPurchasesAsync()

Then I found the wired things:

one of the two acknowledgePurchase() will get a DEVELOPER_ERROR(respond code 5), and the debug message is "Server error! Please try again!";

possible cases:

1. 1st acknowledgePurchase() get DEVELOPER_ERROR, 2th acknowledgePurchase() get successfully
2. 1st acknowledgePurchase() get successfully, 2th acknowledgePurchase() get DEVELOPER_ERROR **[This is the most common case]**
3. both acknowledgePurchase() get successfully

testing with billing client library version is 3.0.0/2.2.0/2.1.0;

Can anyone explain this? Thanks

Comment: i have also faced this issue but i m getting debug massage ->  ;onAcknowledgePurchaseResponse billingResult.getDebugMessage() : Server error, please try again.

Answer (score 4):

As far as I remember, only one acknowledge can be given per purchase. If an acknowledge is given to a purchase that has already been acknowledged, an error will occur.

Remember to verify if the purchase is already acknowledged before trying to acknowledge it.

```
if (purchase.purchaseState == Purchase.PurchaseState.PURCHASED) {
    if (!purchase.isAcknowledged){
        val acknowledgePurchaseParams = AcknowledgePurchaseParams
            .newBuilder()
            .setPurchaseToken(purchase.purchaseToken)
            .build()

        billingClient.acknowledgePurchase(acknowledgePurchaseParams) {
            // result here
        }
    }
}
```

---

If your code triggers two calls of `acknowledgePurchase` to the same purchase at "the same time", there might be the problem.

---

For further information please refer to https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/integrate